# jQuery Isotope Combination Filters mixed with BBQ Hash History - Need help understanding how to

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope, jquery-bbq

I am trying to understand how to use [Combination filters](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/combination-filters.html) with [Jquery BBQ Hash History](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/hash-history.html).

What I want to do is have the user filter by Logos, Identity or Branding. If the user clicks Logos, I want them to then be able to subfilter by "Non-Profit, Education, Retail" etc. I know combination filters work fine without the jquery BBQ code implemented, but I would like to do both.

```
    $optionSets.find('.filter-main a').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    // don't proceed if already selected
    if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
      return;
    }
    changeSelectedLink( $this );
        // get href attr, remove leading #
    var href = $this.attr('href').replace( /^#/, '' ),
        // convert href into object
        // i.e. 'filter=.inner-transition' -> { filter: '.inner-transition' }
        option = $.deparam( href, true );
    // apply new option to previous
    $.extend( isotopeOptions, option );
    // set hash, triggers hashchange on window
    $.bbq.pushState( isotopeOptions );
    isOptionLinkClicked = true;
    return false;
  });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See http://support.metafizzy.co/2011/isotope-combo-filters-hash-links.html

```
$(function(){
  var $container = $('#container'),
      filters = {},
      // get filter from hash, remove leading '#'
      filterSelector = window.location.hash.slice(1);

  $('#filters a').click(function(){
    // store filter value in object
    // i.e. filters.color = 'red'
    var $this = $(this),
        name = $this.attr('data-filter-name'),
        value = $this.attr('data-filter-value'),
        isoFilters = [],
        filterName, prop;

    filters[ name ] = value;

    for ( prop in filters ) {
      isoFilters.push( filters[ prop ] );
    }

    var filterSelector = isoFilters.join('');

    // trigger isotope if its ready
    if ( $container.data('isotope') ) {
      $container.isotope({ filter: filterSelector });
    }

    window.location.hash = filterSelector;

    // toggle highlight
    $this.parents('ul').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $this.parent().addClass('selected');

    return false;

  });


  // if there was a filter, trigger a click on the 
  // corresponding option
  if ( filterSelector ) {
    var selectorClasses = filterSelector.split('.').slice(1);
    $.each( selectorClasses, function( i, selectorClass ) {
      $('#filters a[data-filter-value=".' + selectorClass + '"]').click();
    });
  }

  $('#container').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    filter: filterSelector,
    masonry: {
      columnWidth: 80
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: SOLVED - From the creator himself! Thank you very much Mr. Desandro. It works perfectly. I really looked high and low for any example, but must of overlooked this one. Thanks again.

Comment: It looks like your example breaks the back and forward button functionality. Is this something that only BBQ will help with?

Comment: thanks for the solution here but the link is broken. is it still available anywhere on your support page?